# How to access a value of a "complicated" numeric type in R?

Tags: r

I'm using the mcnemar.test() function in R, in order to examine some statistics hypothesis. The output is a list of type "htest". i.e:

```
McnemarTest<-mcnemar.test(my_data)

Browse[2]> McnemarTest

    McNemar's Chi-squared test

data:  data.matrix(ContingencyTable)
McNemar's chi-squared = 3.6, df = 1, p-value = 0.05778

Browse[2]> class(McnemarTest)
[1] "htest"
```

My question concerns the 2nd element of this list, i.e McnemarTest[2]. It is a list as well.

```
Browse[2]> class(McnemarTest[2])
[1] "list"

Browse[2]> class(McnemarTest[[2]])
[1] "numeric"

Browse[2]> McnemarTest[2]
$parameter
df 
 1 

Browse[2]> McnemarTest[[2]]
df 
 1
```

My question is: How do I isolate only the value "1" in McnemarTest[[2]], and get rid of the "df" string?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `1` is the only value there. It's a named vector of length 1. The value is `1`, the name is `"df"`. You can see this:

```
xx = McnemarTest$parameter
length(xx)
names(xx)
```

If you really want to get rid of the name,

```
xx = unname(xx)
```

But for most things you need to do, unnaming probably isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed. I'm quite new to R, so I haven't thought of that. Many thanks!